# Selenium webdriver not able to identify the Dropdown and a button on the webpage

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I want to select a value from the dropdown and then click on the Next button using Selenium webdriver. In Selenium IDE it is working good but when I try to use the same code in Eclipse it is not working. I tried different solutions but every time I am getting `Unable to locate element` error message. Below is one of the example.

Exception in thread: `"main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"formcode"}`

Solutions I have tried but never worked:

1)

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("formcode"))).selectByVisibleText("Weather Stopper(R) System Plus Ltd. Warranty");
            driver.findElement(By.name("vact")).click();
```

2)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@name='formcode']")));
```

3)

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='formcode']"))).selectByIndex(1);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/input")).click();
```

The HTML code is:

```
<tr>
<TD><SELECT NAME="formcode" size="1">
<option value="">*** Select Warranty Type ***
<OPTION VALUE="1PLUS48">Weather Stopper(R) System Plus Ltd. Warranty<OPTION VALUE="2GOLD52">Golden Pledge</SELECT></TD>
<input type="hidden" name=low_slope_sqs value="">
<input type="hidden" name=addcode value="">
<input type="hidden" name=h_code_no value="">
<input type="hidden" name=steep_slope_sqs value="">
<input type="hidden" name="credit_account"><SPAN ID=messid></SPAN><table border=0 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 align=center>
<TR>
<TD>
<input type=button name="vact" value="Next >>" onclick=submitit('Next1')></TD>
<input type="hidden" name=entrydone value=""> 
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see in the html any dropdown nor button. Please post your full html for the drop down and the button.

Comment: Hi guy..I have updated the html code. Can you please look into it? I captured this code from View Frame source.

Comment: Is the dropdown inside `iframe`?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate elements inside `iframe` you need to switch to it first

```
driver.switchTo.frame(frame ID);
// or
driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(frameLocator));
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
// or
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());
```

As a side note, when you have long text with unique characters like `"Weather Stopper(R) System Plus Ltd. Warranty"` it better to use `selectByValue` or `selectByIndex`. When selecting by text the `select` might fall even on one white space that you missed.